# Get selected ID in Angular 2 click

Tags: angular

I am trying to do something like below - pass the selected id to the component code, but this does not work or seems to work only intermittently (possibly some kind of timing issue?).

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of userList">
    <td>{{ user.firstName }} {{ user.lastName }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.status}}</td>
    <td><a (click)="goToAccount(user.id)">{{user.userName}}</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: It is actually crashing somewhere beyond this point, so apparently this does work.

Comment: Can you post your user object, and also the userList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  should be using something as below

```
<ul>
     <li *ngFor="let user of userList ;" (click)="getID(user.id)">
       {{user.firstName}}
    </li>
   </ul>
</ul>
<br>
    <span *ngIf="clickedID">   Clicked ID {{clickedID}}</span>
       `
```

**Typescript Method**

```
 getID(id:number){
    this.clickedID=id;

  }
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Jz8G4um8M24gj5O5jCyT?p=preview)**

Comment: +1 I will vote for the logic, but i guess you should help the OP, around his code. Introducing something diff might confuse him.

Comment: What is the index for?

Comment: @DannyEllisJr. index is to keep track of the index of the element in the loop. not relevant to your post, that was a fork of my previous answer

Comment: @Smit, yeah you were right. I confused him but comment explains him

Comment: @DannyEllisJr. was this helpful if so upvote too?

Answer (score 1):

User object:

```
export class User{
id: string;
firstName: string;
LastName: string;
status: string;
userName: string;
}
```

in componenet ts:

```
userList: User[];

contructor()
{
this.userList = [];
}

goToAccount(id: any)
{
console.log(id);
}
```

html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of userList">
    <td>{{ user.firstName }} {{ user.lastName }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.status}}</td>
    <td><a (click)="goToAccount(user.id)">{{user.userName}}</a></td>
</tr>
```

This is the nearest simple solution i can think off.

Comment: the **User** can be an interface instead of a class.